# Is there a way to create a subfolder in the resources folder in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, resources, directory

This might be an overly simple question, but I am a beginner at programming for the iPhone with Xcode.  My project uses a lot of picture files for UIImageView animation arrays.  I add all of the pictures into my resource file but the resources folder is getting a bit unwieldy.  Is there a way to add subfolders in resources that do not change or mess up any of the code that I have already created?  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select a group of files in the Xcode organizer, right click on them, and choose "Group" from the contextual popup menu. This will create a subfolder containing them. This subfolder is organizational only, and will not exist in your .app.

Comment: Great!  Thank you.  I didn't know how "grouping" affected the structure or code and didn't want to start messing with my program unless I knew what it meant.

Comment: And if you did want to create resource subdirectories in the built app, you can add them to your project as "folder references" and drag that folder reference into the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase. (This is normally not what you want, but it's what I wanted and I found this question so it might be helpful to someone.)

Answer (score 1):

Right click and select Add > New Group.